# Bootstrap grid 2x2 stops growing horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm having some problems with my layout.
Im trying to make a menu which has a header and a 2x2 tile grid, which has to be 1x4 on smaller screens.

[Goal - Big screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvTjF.png) 
(Red = Header, Green = Tile)

On a small screen everything works fine, it shows the headerbar, and the 4 tiles underneath like this:

[Goal and actual - Small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV6LA.png)

When I resize the screen to make it bigger, at some point it gets to the 2x2 grid but when I resize it to go even bigger the grid stops growing horizontally, which makes it look like this:

[Actual - Big screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8iX1.png)

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="overlay-content" id="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tile col-md-6 border">
            <a href="#">asdf</a>
         </div>
         <div class="tile col-md-6 border">
             <a href="#">asfd</a>
         </div>                
         <div class="tile col-md-6 border">
             <a href="#">asdf</a>
         </div>
         <div class="tile col-md-6 border">
             <a href="#">asdf</a>
         </div> 
     </div>
 </div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
.overlay {    
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.overlay-header{    
    border:10px;
    font-family:fontNavbar;
    filter: invert(100%);
}

.overlay-content {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display:flex;
}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `container-fluid` should be a class, not an id attribute.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have enough content to force the columns to their full 50% width, add the following CSS (and convert the `container-fluid` ID from an id to a class):

```
.overlay-content.container-fluid,
.overlay-content.container-fluid > .row {
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2a6w3sve/